# How to set focus on validation summary when validation fails in page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

After clicking the Login button I am showing error message, But I am trying  to focus along with error message.

Comment: It would be nice if you show some code

Answer (score 0):

you can try some thing like this

```
function btnLogin_Click(){
if(Page_ClientValidate()) {
    return true; }
else {     
    var validationSummary= document.getElementById('<%=vsLoginValidation .ClientID%>');  ///vsLoginValidation is the  id of validation control
    if(validationSummary!= null)
    {
        vsummary.scrollIntoView(true);          
    }
    return false;
 }
```

}